# Initialize dynamically the var filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

What I'm trying to achieve is to initialize the "filter" variable dynamically based on what my method gets.

- Initializing it to null throws an error.
- Leaving it empty throws error.
- Setting it to a generic type throws an error
- Setting it to a new `BsonDocument` also throws an error

This is my code:

```
var filter=null;

if (id != 0)
    if (subID != 0)
        //Get Specific Categories
        filter = builder.Eq("Categories.Sub.id", id) & builder.Eq("Categories.Sub.Custom.id", subID);
    else
        //Get SubCategories
        filter = builder.Eq("Categories.Sub.id", id);
else
    //Get Generic Categories
    filter = new BsonDocument();
```

I've been searching but nobody seems to have my problem or I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Var is not a dynamic variable, it is a keyword for [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference). These are very different concepts. The key issue is that in your code snippet the compiler can not figure out what kind of variable you want your `var` to be.

```
var myNumber = 3; // myNumber is inferred by the compiler to be of type int.

int myNumber = 3; // this line is considered by the computer to be identical to the one above.
```

The inferred type of a var variable does not change.

```
var myVariable = 3;
myVariable = "Hello"; // throws an error because myVariable is of type int
```

The type of dynamic variables *can* change.

```
dynamic myVariable = 3;
myVariable = "Hello"; // does not throw an error.
```

The compiler *must* be able to determine the type of an object when a var variable is created;

```
var myVariable = null; // null can be anything, the compiler can not figure out what kind of variable you want.

var myVariable = (BsonDocument)null; // by setting the variable to a null instance of a specific type the compiler can figure out what to set var to.
```

Comment: Thanks! I though the type `var` was like the javascript type. It worked after changing the type from var to dynamic

Answer (score 0):

With `var` it's an implicit type and you can initialize a implicit type variable to `null` since it can be both value type and reference type; and value type can't be assigned to null (unless otherwise it's made nullable explicitly).

Thus instead of saying `var filter=null;` you should explicitly specify the type

```
BsonDocument filter = null;
```

Comment: Didn't accepted because if I set my filter to `BsonDocument` then throws me errors here `filter = builder.Eq("Categories.Sub.id", id);` because it returns a different type.